# One-liner to calculate the score based on two dicts

Tags: python

I have the following table of values:

```
scores = {
    "proxy": 300,
    "vpn": 500,
    "tor": 900,
    "recent_abuse": 1000,
}
```

And this data with booleans

```
data = {
    "proxy": False,
    "vpn": True,
    "tor": False,
    "recent_abuse": False,
}
```

What I want is to know if it possible to calculate in a single line (probably using itertools) a score based on `data`

My current code is this:

```
if data["proxy"]:
    score += 300
if data["vpn"]:
    score += 500
if data["tor"]:
    score += 900
if data["recent_abuse"]:
    score += 1000
```

Comment: sum([scores[key] for key in scores if data[key]])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a list generator:

```
scores = {
    "proxy": 300,
    "vpn": 500,
    "tor": 900,
    "recent_abuse": 1000,
}

data = {
    "proxy": False,
    "vpn": True,
    "tor": False,
    "recent_abuse": False,
}

score = sum(scores[x] for x in scores if data.get(x, False))
print(score)
```

Out:

```
500
```

Comment: You answer also works if the key doesn't exists on `scores`, thank you

Comment: This is not a list comprehension but a generator expression. In this case it is more efficient than a list comprehension as you do not first create an intermediate list.

Comment: @ Forss: Thx, for pointing out that typo.

Answer (score 9):

```py
total = sum(scores[k] for k, v in data.items() if v)
```

Better names for `k`: `field_name`. `v`: `field_value`.

---

I derived it in this way:

```
total = 0
for k, v in data.items():
    if v:
        total += scores[k]
```

And from there it is easy to fold it into a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
score = sum([scores[k] for k in scores.keys() if data[k]])
print(score)
# 500
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension to get the scores to add, then sum them up.

```py
score += sum(scores[flag] for flag, enabled in result.items() if enabled)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum([scores[k]*data.get(k, False) for k in scores])
```

Comment: I think your answer would be improved with a little explanation about why this works. Multiplying by a boolean isn't a super common operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
score += sum([a*b for a, b in zip(scores.values(), data.values())])
```